# Alternative needed for unstack

Tags: r

I have some irregular data in one column.

```
my.table <-read.table(text="ticker,date,last
a,12/20/2011,289295
a,12/21/2011,NA
a,12/27/2011,297001
a,12/28/2011,NA
b,12/20/2011,151253
b,12/21/2011,NA
b,12/27/2011,152413
b,12/28/2011,NA
b,1/4/2012,NA
d,12/21/2011,98.52
d,12/28/2011,99.36
d,1/4/2012,103.22", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE,sep = ",")
```

I usually use `unstack` to reshape my data in a data.frame. But unstack is not working because the number of elements differ and cannot be put in a data.frame format.

```
my.expression <-last~ticker
unstacked <- unstack(my.table, my.expression ) #Not a data.frame
```

I would like my table to look like this:

```
               a       b     c
12/20/2011  289295  151253   NA
12/21/2011  NA      NA     98.52
12/27/2011  297001  152413   NA
12/28/2011  NA      NA     99.36
1/4/2012    NA      NA     103.22
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to combine vectors with different length within a list in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746587/how-to-combine-vectors-with-different-length-within-a-list-in-r)

Comment: @Ritchie Cotton - My problem is a reshape/unstack problem for a single column. The post you linked to is solved with cbind'ing several data.frames.

Comment: @RichieCotton: I don't think so. That question starts with a list of vectors and ends with a matrix. This starts with a data frame and ends with a data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the `reshape2` package?

```
library("reshape2")
dcast(my.table, date~ticker)
```

which gives

```
Using last as value column: use value.var to override.
        date      a      b      d
1   1/4/2012     NA     NA 103.22
2 12/20/2011 289295 151253     NA
3 12/21/2011     NA     NA  98.52
4 12/27/2011 297001 152413     NA
5 12/28/2011     NA     NA  99.36
```

or if you want to convert the dates to internal date format first

```
my.table$date <- as.Date(my.table$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
dcast(my.table, date~ticker)
```

which gives

```
Using last as value column: use value.var to override.
        date      a      b      d
1 2011-12-20 289295 151253     NA
2 2011-12-21     NA     NA  98.52
3 2011-12-27 297001 152413     NA
4 2011-12-28     NA     NA  99.36
5 2012-01-04     NA     NA 103.22
```

Comment: Super thanks. Didn't know about `reshape2`. The original `reshape` was not giving me what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

```
 with(my.table, tapply(last, list(date, ticker),  I))
                a      b      d
1/4/2012       NA     NA 103.22
12/20/2011 289295 151253     NA
12/21/2011     NA     NA  98.52
12/27/2011 297001 152413     NA
12/28/2011     NA     NA  99.36
```

(It sorts alpha-wise because of not having a date classed variable.)

```
 my.table$date.dt <- as.Date(my.table$date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
 with(my.table, tapply(last, list(date.dt, ticker),  I))
                a      b      d
2011-12-20 289295 151253     NA
2011-12-21     NA     NA  98.52
2011-12-27 297001 152413     NA
2011-12-28     NA     NA  99.36
2012-01-04     NA     NA 103.22
```

To address a comment below: If you need it as a dataframe rather than a table you will need to wrap as.data.frame around the results:

```
as.data.frame(with(my.table, tapply(last, list(date.dt, ticker),  identity)))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the "I" at the end? I know I(x) means as.is, but I do not understand how your code ends us being a data.frame.

Comment: You just need some function that returns an atomic value unchanged. It would also have worked with the `c` or the `identity` functions. And it's not a data.frame ... its a "table" which behaves as a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is in the file `data.txt` try this.   The arguments refer to the file name, the fact that the data has a header, the field separator character is comma, the first column is to be split on, the second column is the time index and the format of the time index is as indicated.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo("data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", split = 1, index = 2, 
       format= "%m/%d/%Y")
```

The resulting zoo object represents the time series with one column per ticker:

```
> z
                a      b      d
2011-12-20 289295 151253     NA
2011-12-21     NA     NA  98.52
2011-12-27 297001 152413     NA
2011-12-28     NA     NA  99.36
2012-01-04     NA     NA 103.22
```

The above reads it in and transforms it all at once but if you have already read it into `my.table` using the code in the question then its just this:

```
z <- read.zoo(my.table, split = 1, index = 2, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```